# Create Empty Text File In All Folders With Folder Name

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder named **Process_Docs** and have about **200 folders** inside that folder with part numbers. What I would like to do is create a blank text file in each of those folders that is the name of that folder. I cannot seem to find an example of how to do this with a batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a:d /b C:\Process_Docs') do type NUL >>C:\Process_Docs\%%f\%%f.txt
```

(It works for folders that contain spaces.)

**EDIT**:

Okay, try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a:d /b *') do type NUL >>%%f\%%f.txt
```

Save this as a batch/cmd file and copy it to C:\Windows (or some other *path* folder). Then you can call it from anywhere and it will work on the *subfolders* of that current folder.

Comment: Thanks. How would I specify this to run in the current directory?

Comment: I should have been more specific. I would like to place this batch file in ANY folder so I could add the text files to all of the folders within.

Comment: Replace `*` with `%~dp0`

Comment: EXCELLENT! Thanks very much. In addition, how would I add an extension to the folder name.txt?  Folder = ABC  TextFile = ABC-TOP.txt

Comment: @Patrick, my test worked the way I posted it, when would it not work right?

Comment: ... `%%f.txt` at the end of the line is the filename, `%%f` gets replaced with the foldername. You can write anything else here that you want.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the help. This is just what I need. I am quite new with batch files, but they are quite interesting and helpful. I am not sure the difference between "*" & "%~dp0" but I see they both work.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the answer by @KekuSemau but will run in any folder and supports long filename elements like spaces.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a:d /b') do type NUL >>"%%f\%%~nxf.txt"
```

If you need to process an entire tree then it needs a `/s`  after the `/b` and before the `'`